# Regex for cron pattern not working

Tags: linux, regex, cron, javascript

Tried to create a (simplified) regex for cron patterns for myself and came up with the following one:

```
^(((\d+(,\d+)*)|(\d+-\d+)|(\*(\/\d+)?))(\s+(\d+(,\d+)*)|(\d+-\d+)|(\*(\/\d+)?)){4})$
```

This is generated by

```
var variant1 = "\\d+(,\\d+)*";
var variant2 = "\\d+-\\d+";
var variant3 = "\\*(\\/\\d+)?";
var variants = "(" + variant1 + ")|(" + variant2 + ")|(" + variant3 + ")";
var regex_cron = "^((" + variants + ")(\\s+" + variants + "){4})$";
```

For a lot of cron patterns this is working just fine:

```
* 4 45 6 7
5 4 45 6 7
*/5 3,4 45,6,8 6 5
```

But if I use an asterisk in "group" 2 or higher, it fails:

```
4 * * * *
```

I know that there are a couple of regular expressions for recognizing cron patterns available on the internet, but I really would like to know where I went wrong during creating the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probleme in your regex lies in the grouping of the second part:

```
var regex_cron = "^((" + variants + ")(\\s+" + variants + "){4})$";
                                        ---
```

should be :

```
var regex_cron = "^((" + variants + ")(\\s+(" + variants + ")){4})$";
                                           !                !
```

Because as you wrote it the \s+ (---) belongs only to the first part of the OR and the 2 next one don't match because there is a space.

May be it would be better practice to group the variants var together:

```
var variants = "((" + variant1 + ")|(" + variant2 + ")|(" + variant3 + "))";
```

There is a good place to test your regexp: http://www.regexr.com/

And this regexp could be simplified, and in the current state it doesn't match the string that will be the cron command, that should come before the $ matching the end of the line.

Comment: You're right and it's kind of obvious once someone spells it out for me. Thx. Actually I don't check entries of the crontab file but patterns for cron4j (which can be entered by the user and therefore have to be checked).